# Se puede hacer una función en javascript que se ejecute cuando cambie el contenido de un <div>?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una ventana modal que muestra unos productos y aparte tengo un `<p>` que indica la suma del precio total de los productos que se encuentran en un div específico.

Lo que actualmente tengo en el script externo ya esta funcionando y quería adicionalmente poner una función que en una condicional si el `<div>` este vació ponga el valor de "--.--".

modal:

```
<div class="vent-modal">
   <div class="contenedor">
   </div>
   <div>
      <p id="valor-cont">--.--</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
let ventana = document.querySelector(".vent-modal");
let content = document.querySelector(".contenedor");
let suma_cont = document.querySelector("#valor_cont");

loadFuncs();

//código de idea
//
// function loadFuncs() {
//    ventana.addEventListener('***', condicion)
// }
// function condicion() {   
//    if (content.length === 0) {
//       suma_cont.innerHTML = "--.--"
//    }
// }
```

El suma_cont cambia su valor al haber items dentro de un array de objetos donde toma el valor de cada objeto y lo va sumando con otro en el caso de haber varios, caso contrario debería encerarse o en este caso ponerse "--.--".

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres... ¿Ese `suma_cont` cuando cambia o porque debe cambiar?  Si cambia supongo que será por algun otro cacho de código de javascript en alguna parte... ¿no puedes controlarlo allí mejor?

Comment: Venia yo a decir algo similar... Si el contenido del div cambia probablemente es porque alguna funcion se ejecutó que hizo que el DOM debajo de el cambiara... pues ahi mismo donde se hac e el llamado a esa funcion, pues se puede hacer el llamado a la funcion `condicion` del ejemplo... no?

Comment: O sino, podrías hacer uso de la clase [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)